# android Zoom-to-Fit All Markers on Google Map v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

How to zoom in/out the map view such a way that it cover all markers?

i am reviewing sample code of gmap V2 given in sdk.  It lays on sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try using `LatLngBounds`   :

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(Latlng1);
builder.include(Latlng2);
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20));
```

Comment: I am using the same but it is not covering all markers. It hangs som where between.

Comment: what do you mean by: "It hangs som where between"? are you including all Latlng point in the builder?

Comment: Yes I am including the same way you have told, even it finds between latlong but not zoomed view is seen....

Comment: did you get any answer? it is also not working for me too

Comment: Not working for me too..

Comment: this solutions is working for me just fine...

Comment: @DanielG.R. well it worked well for me. Maybe there were changes in the API by Google. Please check the documentation.

Comment: It works, you are right, excuse me :)

Comment: It didn´t let me remove it until x hours, done ;)

Comment: Thanks for removing it.

Comment: I am using the same but it is not covering all markers.

Comment: Worked for me also :) THanks

Comment: // Kotlin Code if someone needs:
        var allMarkers: MutableList<Marker> = mutableListOf()
        allMarkers.add(marker1)
        allMarkers.add(marker2)
        val builder = LatLngBounds.Builder()
        allMarkers.forEach { // All marker array
            builder.include(it.position)
        }
        val bounds = builder.build()
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100))