# Add multiple markers to the google map and zoom to include all of them

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using the following code to add markers to google map and create bounds.
What I am trying to do is add the markers and zoom in a way that all of them are visible in a map that has fixed height

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();  
for(Location loc: locations) {  
  MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(loc.lat, loc.lon);  
  googleMap.addMarker(marker);  
  builder.include(marker.getPosition());  
}    

LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();  
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 5);  
googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Whether all icons will appear or not depends on the value I add for padding.
If I increase the value all show up. Otherwise others are hidden.
How do I come up with the correct value for the padding taking into account that my googleMap has a fixed set width?

Answer (score 0):

Try set a center of the position where you want initiate the map (set a coor with latitude and longitude of any of your markers) and set a level of zoom:

```
LatLng center = centro = new LatLng(lat, long);

CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(center).zoom(17).bearing(0).tilt(0).build();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: This doesn’t work. Centers in the bounds (I think) but none of the markers are visible

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is correct and it may depend on your specifics on how to show your markers on the map. If you will look on this [sample](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2015/06/android-maximum-zoom-in-google-map.html) code, the developer provided a different value for padding.

```
/*initialize the padding for map boundary/
int padding = 50;
/*create the bounds from latlngBuilder to set into map camera/
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
/*create the camera with bounds and padding to set into map/
cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
/*call the map call back to know map is loaded or not/
map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
/*set animated zoom camera into map/
map.animateCamera(cu);

}
});
}
```

Here are some links that provides solution and own implementation using **`newLatLngBounds`**:

- [Fit All Markers Of GoogleMap In Android](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2015/11/26/fit-all-markers-of-googlemap-in-android/)
- [android Zoom-to-Fit All Markers on Google Map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414879/5995040)
- [Android map v2 zoom to show all the markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14828739/5995040)

Hope it helps!